# Azure Pipelines Yml Template in Public GitHub Repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a public GitHub repo with some Azure Pipelines yml template files. I want to create a pipeline that uses these templates. I don't want to use an OAuth based service connection, because the whole concept of an OAuth Service Connection is simply ridiculous for a CI/CD environment since the tokens expire and need to be tied to a specific user. I also don't want to use a GitHub PAT because it seems ridiculous to have a PAT (again tied to a specific user) to access a public GitHub repo.

How can I create my pipeline so it is not tied to a specific user?

I would like to have something like this

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: github
      name: APublicGitHubOrg/APublicGitHubRepo
      ref: ref/heads/master
  
extends:
  template: TheTemplate.yml
```

but that doesn't work because `endpoint` is a required property.

Ok...so how can I create an endpoint for GitHub without tying it to a user or having an expiration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Repository templates requires an endpoint, and GitHub repos require a GitHub service connection for authorization, which requires either `Grant authorization` or `Personal access token`.

If you really want to this feature, please submit a suggestion at website below, product team will evaluate it carefully:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21